# css attributes not changing despite seemingly accurate execution, bootstrap, django

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-font-api, css-specificity

I am trying to style my navbar to remove the small border radius that is default by bootstrap css.

As Well I am trying to implement the google font I have chosen. Despite my seemingly perfect execution,nothing is working.

I am using django, and although for this that doesn't really matter, it just explains some of the syntax.

my links in my HTML file are in the following order:

```
<!-- Loads the path to the static files-->
{%  load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://googleapis.com/css?family=Satisfy" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'music/style.css' %}">
<script src ="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

the HTML attributes I want to manipulate are the following, note the classes

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <!--Header-->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavBar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class = "navbar-brand" href="{% url 'music:index' %}">Viberr</a>
    </div>
```

the div at the top with the class of navbar is the has the border attribute I want to change.

The div with the class navbar-brand is the one I want to apply my google font to.

Here is my linked css file:

```
 body{
    background: white url("images/background1.jpg");
}
.navbar{
    border-radius: 0;
}

.navbar-brand{
    font-family: 'Satisfy', cursive;
}
```

As you can see, unless I am completely missing something there is no reason why this shouldn't work.

Comment: It's likely that your css is less specific than the one you are trying to override. For instance `nav.navbar` is more specific than `.nav`, and will take effect even if the other one was declared last. Use your browser's "inspect" feature to see which css rules are in effect.

Comment: very good, thank you.

Comment: This part of the css spec can be quite hard to understand. There are many questions about it here, and it even has its own tag: [css-specificty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-specificity?sort=active). You can read a good primer about css specificity here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity